# Replace runfile with exec/subprocess.call while passing a namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, spyder

I have a python script that accepts an argument, say `test.py 1` and generates some data. A second script `experiment.py` launches `test.py` repeatedly. I achieve this using `runfile`  in Spyder IDE:

So, `experiment.py` reads something like:

```
experiments = {}
for i in range(10):
    experiments[str(i)] = {}
    runfile(`test.py`, args=str(i), wdir=`/path/to/script/`, namespace=experiments[str(i)])

## some post-processing using data from the dict experiments
```

This allows me to store variables of `test.py` for each call in a separate namespace. Everything works well, but (here comes my question):

**How can I replace `runfile` with `exec` or `subprocess.call`** and be able to pass a namespace and an argument list?

The objective is to run the script from command line rather than Spyder. Just to clarify, I am aware that the best way to perform such a task is to convert `test.py` into a function. However, I am trying to make-do with the current script `test.py` which is quite long.

Comment: Namespaces don't make sense outside of Spyder, do they? I'm not familiar with it but quick Duck Duck Going suggests that the meaning of this parameter is to separate the variables in the subscript from the ones in Spyder itself, which of course you are not running when you aren't.

Comment: `subprocess.run(['test.py', str(i)], check=True, cwd='/path/to/script')`, possibly add `text=True` and `capture_output=True` if you want that. Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `test.py` to save its variables to a file and then loading the file in `experiment.py` instead of using `exec` use `subprocess.run` so that you can run the script from the command line and avoid using the Spyder-specific `runfile` function.

`test.py` will look like this

```
import sys
import json

arg = int(sys.argv[1])

# Your original code here

variables_to_save = {'variable1': variable1, 'variable2': variable2}
with open(f"variables_{arg}.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(variables_to_save, f)
```

and `experiment.py`

```
import subprocess
import json

experiments = {}
for i in range(10):
    experiments[str(i)] = {}
    
    subprocess.run(["python", "test.py", str(i)], cwd="/path/to/script/")
    
    with open(f"variables_{i}.json", "r") as f:
        experiments[str(i)] = json.load(f)
```